# How to avoid a build and deployment of dependencies which have no code changes

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, automated-deploy, incremental-build

I'm doing a proof of concept on continuous integration and whether our development team will benefit from automated builds and automated deployments to reduce human error.
I've already come quite far in the process but have some questions on how to configure our incremental builds to avoid rebuilding of dependencies that had no code changes.
In addition I’d like our deployment tool to identify and deploy only assemblies rebuilt as a result of a code change.

We already use Microsoft products like TFS for source control, Visual Studio for development and Team Foundation Build for continuous integration builds. We’re currently leaning toward InRelease for deployment as it seem to integrate well with Team Foundation Build.

But first, here is our current setup...

1. There are 200+ C# solution files, each containing one or more projects.  It is not practical in the environment to combine these projects into less solutions, i.e. by design. Projects within a solution uses project references to resolve dependencies and file references to projects in other solutions. As far as I know, this is the recommended approach by Microsoft when dealing with a large amount of projects.
2. We use a "branch by feature" strategy e.g. isolated development on concurrent features branches which is merged up to a stable Main branch when complete. When it's time for a release, a release is branched from main and isolated for hotfixes and deployment. The feature branches and main branch have a CI build triggered by code check-ins. Releases will mostly like be manually executed from InRelease against a selected release branch. A release will be deployed through various environments including INTEGRATION/TEST, UAT and ultimately to all our clients. We're still fleshing out the details of branching strategy, but that's a question for another time.

**The current problems to solve:**

**1. Avoid rebuilding of dependencies that have no code changes...**

When we deploy new functionality or a patch to a client, we want to push the absolute minimum in files. Our company has a very large customer base (thousands of customers) with sometimes slow internet connections, so doing a full deployment of all assemblies (200+) to every customer is not an option. I've partially solved the problem by setting up incremental builds which correctly rebuilds only changed projects as expected but also rebuilds all the dependent projects even though NO CODE CHANGES were made to them. This results in both the changed assemblies and dependencies having new timestamps. If we use the change of timestamp to identify which assemblies to deploy, then this would result  in deployment of functionally unchanged assemblies. The goal here is to deploy only assemblies where the code has changed and assemblies where breaking changes occur.

For example:

Solution B, has a project called Project B
Solution A, has a project called Project A

Project B -> Project A  (where Project A has a file dependency on Project B)

When a **non-breaking** change is made in Project A, say to the interior of a method, then the expected result is: only A is built and therefore a candidate for deployment.
When a **breaking** change is made in Project A then that will break Project B, the expected result is: Both A and B is built and therefore a candidate for deployment.
Currently MSBuild rebuilds all dependents regardless, which is not what we want.

**2. Automatically identify which assemblies should be deployed...**

I have a partial solution to the problem.
When a build is performed, my build process template is configured to run a MSBuild script containing a list of solutions to build in a particular order. 
This operation is performed in the build agent’s workspace. Every time a new build is performed the build process template creates an unique drop folder in the format  and copies the binaries from the build agent workspace to the drop folder. This is out of the box functionality taken care of by the standard build process template. The build has been configured not to clear the build agent workspace, so the first time it runs it will build all projects within a solution but subsequent builds will only build projects that have code changes or is dependent on other projects (incremental build?). Therefore unchanged assemblies will have the original time stamps and changed assemblies will have new timestamps. 
We have a tool that can do folder comparisons between drop folders and output the results to a txt file. This allows us to identify which binaries have been added/changed/removed since the last deployment. It also gives us the added benefit of comparing the list of actual artefacts to a manifest of expected artefacts as defined by the developer. This will ensure that no assemblies get deployed that has not been specified and proven to be unit tested.

The question is how can be we leverage InRelease to deploy only the required files as per the example above and not all files in the drop folder?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install a TFS Proxy in before your build machine, this reduce the net traffic
2. You will start with a branch strategy like Service Pack, you can read a documentation about in ALM Rangers guidance... And adapt you process template to build just the part of code changed. I think in BRD Lite, another guidance by ALM Rangers, you will found more information.